# How to remove last key:value pair in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

I am very new to JavaScript and I am trying to figure out how to set a function to remove the last key:value pair to the right, much like array.pop for an array. This is an assignment I am working on. It seems confusing to me because, from my limited understanding of JS their is no specific order in a list of properties in an object. If anyone has any insight I would appreciate it. Here is the object:

```
var array = {length:0, size:big, smell:strange};
```

this is where I have started to go, but just having a hard time completing the function:

```
array.pop = function() {
//...
};
```

Ultimately I would like it to turn out like this:

```
array = {length:0, size:big};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Objects have no order, so there's no last key.

Comment: FYI, it's not a good practice to name a variable `array` when the data structure is NOT an array.  You're just asking for someone to make a mistake in understanding or modifying your code.  It's like it is trying to intentionally mislead the reader.

Comment: @jfriend00  I would have to agree with you on that...I think my professor has gone mad... he asked that we name it array. Its all a bit strange and I think he's trying to encourage thinking outside of the box or something.

Comment: Are you sure the data doesn't look like this: `var array = [{length: 0}, {size: big}, {smell: strange}];`?  Then, both the name and the question would make more sense.

Comment: yeah, the assignment is basically to simulate an array with an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects do not have any defined order of properties so there is no "last" property.  You have to remove a property by name, not position.

You can, of course, iterate over the properties and inspect them as you iterate and decide whether you want to delete any given property by looking at its name.  Some javascript implementations will preserve the order that properties were added, but that is specifically not guaranteed by the ECMAScript specification so it cannot be relied upon.

Comment: Does it really happen that they are not in order? It is not guaranteed, but I didn't see any case when order wasn't preserved...

Comment: Okay, that's kind of what I thought...just having a lot of doubts due to the assignment. Probably a trick question :) ...Thanks for your help!

Comment: @FlashThunder - Modern browsers seem to preserve order, but we have no idea if they always do in all circumstances.  In any case, if you need order, then a different data structure should be used rather than rely on an undocumented behavior that is explicitly not guaranteed.

Comment: true, was just curious... :-)

Answer (score 3):

This will work

```
const car = {
  color: 'blue',
  brand: 'Ford'
}
let keys = Object.keys(car)
delete car[keys[keys.length-1]]
console.log(car)
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is good for those situtations where the key is dynamically generated numbers like 0,1,2,3,4 etc

```
const myObject = {
  0: 'somestring',
  1: 42,
  2: false
};

delete myObject[`${Object.keys(myObject).length-1}`]
console.log(myObject);
```

***output:***

> Object { 0: "somestring", 1: 42 }

this one line logic may not good when key is a string. So, carefully use it.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet below **demonstrates** that *"objects have no order"*, and an [inefficient] workaround: use an array alongside of the object, to store the order that the properties were added to the object.

Click to add random properties, and note the order that they appear below.

- In CodePen (or on my webserver) the properties seem to be stored **sorted *numerically*** (even though they're stored as strings).
- However, in the snippet below they seem to be ordered **randomly**.
  Neither are the order that the properties are added.

It should be noted:

> Unlike what common belief suggests (perhaps due to other programming languages like [delete in C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/delete-operator-cpp?view=vs-2019)), the delete operator has **nothing** to do with directly freeing memory. Memory management is done indirectly via breaking references.
> <sub>**More info:** [`delete` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#description) and [Memory Management](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management).</sub>

```js
var obj={}, // object to store properties (keys) and values
    props=[]; // array to store property names

add.onclick=function(){
  var prop=rnd(), val=rnd(); // get 2 random numbers
  obj[ prop ] = val;  // add property & value → object
  props.push( prop ); // add property name → array
  updateInfo(); // display object
}

del.onclick=function(){
  var lastProp=props.pop(); // get/remove last property name in array
  delete obj[ lastProp ]; // remove property
  updateInfo(); //display object
}

function rnd(){return Math.floor(Math.random()*1E5);} // random 0-99999

function updateInfo(){ // show pretty object 
  info.innerHTML=JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/[\{\}]+/g,"").replaceAll(',','<br>');
}
```

```html
<button id='add'>add new property</button>
<button id='del'>delete last added</button>
<div id='info'></div>
```